# How to style formtastic radio buttons

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, radio-button, formtastic

My customer wants an traffic light styled review form. Vertically alinged radio buttons, colored in green, yellow and red.

I could get the alignment done, but fail at styling the buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Radio buttons are only circles. You can not change their color using css but you can create an image like a radio button with the color you want and using javascript and a hidden input make it acts as a radio button.

Answer (score 0):

Radio buttons etc are notoriously difficult to style in CSS. Javascript based solutions are usually the preferred method if you really have to style them.

http://ryanfait.com/resources/custom-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/